# UINavigationController in iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I am new in Objective-C and iOS. I followed [UINavigationController](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN4JRic6TM8).

In the first 2:30min off the video, He uses AppDelegate interface and implementation and There are some codes provided there which I don't have in my application.

In the interface he has:

```
@Class ViewController;
...
@property(strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
```

which I don't have.

And in the implementation of AppDelegate, before he start to define `navigationViewController`, he has some lines of codes in  `didFinishLaunchingWithOption` like:

```
self.windows = [[UIWindows alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.windows.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.windows makeKeyAndVisible]
return YES;
```

I got warning on `self.viewController`.

but I just have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

To nix the NavigationViewController, he adds this line:

```
 UINavigationController *navigationViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController
self.windows.rootViewController = navigationViewController;
```

When I added this code I faced an error (warning on `self.viewController` at the end).
When I run the project, it just show the navigation at the top, but the TableView that I created before, is disappeared.
Can you help me how can I fix this problem? My simulator is version 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming since this is Part 12 of his youtube series, he is building off previous code.

Regardless, there are many ways to add the rootViewController to the window. (programmatically, via Storyboards, etc.)

The simplest way to get a project setup which would match his tutorial would be:

Create a new "Single View" Project in Xcode and DO NOT enable Storyboards.

This will create a project with an AppDelegate, ViewController class and ViewController xib.

(If you selected Universal app you will have 2 xib files)

Open up the AppDelegate for this newly created project and it should very close to his screencast...

Good luck!

(note this was verified with XCode 4.3.3)

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the title bar and end of my description the XCode is 5.1. the AppDelegate does not include these codes.

Comment: 5.1 is the iOS SDK. These instructions should work (or be very close) in all recent versions of XCode. The code will be generated when you create a new project as described.

Comment: I create a new project in XCode. The generated code in AppDelegate is exactly the same that I said. but you are right about iOS version and XCode. Mine also in XCode 4.3.3.

Comment: I appreciate for your answer, it was useful.